# AutoMapper Generic conversion of DTO to Domain Entity in Service Layer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, automapper

In my ASP.Net MVC based application's Service Layer I have an abstract Service that is setup like this:

```
public abstract class Service<TEntity, TDto> : IService<TDto> 
where TEntity : BaseEntity where TDto : IBaseDto
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity> _repository;

        protected Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _repository = repository;
        }     


        public virtual void Create(TDto entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------
            // HOWTO: Convert from TDto to TEntity
            //--------------------------------------------------
            _repository.Add(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();         
        }
}
```

The intent is to keep common methods in this abstract class so I don't repeat this in every entities implementation.

Now the problem is that I need some way to convert `TDto` to `TEntity` in the `Create(TDto entity)` method above. I can't seem to figure out how I can do this with AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get an instance of the mapper with DI:

```
private IMapper _mapper;

protected Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository, IMapper mapper)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _repository = repository;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

You can then use that _mapper instance to map from your dto to your entity like this:

```
public virtual void Create(TDto dto)
{
    if (dto == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dto");
    }
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TEntity>(dto);
    _repository.Add(entity);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();         
}
```

With the mapper configuration something like:

```
var mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Models.DtoModel, EntityModel>();
});

mapConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var iMapper = new Mapper(mapConfig) as IMapper;
```

Comment: You should probably include some code showing how to create the mapping as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the `IMapper`?

Comment: Best place to go from here is probably the documentation for automapper.
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper